# Is there anything "objective" about C# 4.0, or ruby-like?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, objective-c, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

This is a very "high-level" question. I'm looking for insight into this problem that c# has.

It has so many features that it supports almost ANY task, alas there are alternatives that are better suited for some tasks.

With the advent of MVC(old news) + ruby, people are starting to have "fun" AND getting things to work.

C# seems like a "get it done" language. It has so many libraries that knowing what to use has become more important than anything else.

**So... IF one had to use C# to develop an "objective" oriented design AND having a ruby-like fun doing it... What features would best suit this "style"?**
//C# 4 included//

PS. By objective i do not mean object oriented. "The Objective-C model of object-oriented programming is based on message passing to object instances. In Objective-C one does not call a method; one sends a message."

Comment: Many libraries...? Perhaps you have the .NET framework in mind. Moreover, you can hardly develop something that is not object oriented in C# mainly because everything in C# is an object.

Comment: what's the difference between sending a message to an object or calling a method on an object? IMHO  these can be used synonymously

Comment: :) love the comments. No... Ruby is not about naked boys or girls :) Yes i have the .net framework in mind. There is a difference, it leads to two different programming styles. What i am looking for is a way to take advantage of .net by using c# 4.0. I have a ruby background. Both ruby and c# have "rails" now (mvc). So can i adopt a ruby programming style now that c# 4.0 is dynamic?

How would this look like?

Comment: C# is still totally objective. They added features, they didn't remove them.

Comment: There is a difference between sending a message and calling a method. Method calls are static, message dispatch is dynamic. For example, NSUndoManager works by recording the messages it receives and relaying them to a target object when undo is invoked. Messaging is a layer of abstraction on top of method calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a VERY interesting read on the subject:

http://blog.wekeroad.com/2010/08/09/csharps-new-clothes

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use .NET and the 'Ruby' style, then why not try IronRuby?

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing is could find is CCR and DSS.
Check you VPL on Microsoft Robotics Studio 2008 R3.

This approach seems to best fit the message-passing "feature" and promises to "objectivize" .net development.